# Disable https in the workspace

Tags: cloud9-ide

I'm working on a project where i don't need the `https` protocol, so for this reason I would like to disable it on my workspace. I need just the normal `http` protocol

It is possible?

Answer (score 3):

As you may have noticed, previews in C9 default to https. To view with http you'll need to pop-out the preview (diagonal double arrow next to URL) to a new tab and change to http.